# Доступ к файлам в папке Assets.xcassetts из приложения

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Господа, кто хорошо разбирается в языке swift? Мне нужно получить доступ к одну или нескольким файлам в папке Assets.xcassets из программы. Как это можно сделать и можно ли в принципе?

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду и что хотите сделать?

Comment: @VAndrJ Мне необходимо прочитать файл, находящийся в bundle, или в Assets.xcassets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func readBundle(file:String) -> String {
    var res = ""
    if let asset = NSDataAsset(name: file) ,
        string = String(data:asset.data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        res = string
    }
    return res
}
```

Ответ взят [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36580897/608343).